# First time writing a scripting engine

Tags: programming-languages, scripting, virtual-machine

So I decided to created a stack-based virtual machine and the result came out pretty good (in my opinion!). The first iteration was a basic toy VM.

I did a rewrite to make the VM work more realistically by giving it byte-oriented memory and data stack as well as n-byte oriented opcodes. After much testing, including a fibonacci in opcodes test, the result turned out beautiful, turing complete, and I really enjoyed making it.

I have now decided on another rewrite but to expand it into a scripting engine. I picked up a book called "Game scripting mastery" which talked about creating an entire scripting engine with custom scripting language from scratch.

It was a little overkill for what I wanted to do but the ideas of it were helpful but I'm hoping to take some better approaches than what the book shows.

As a scripting engine, my intention with this engine is to execute bytecode created from a normal C compiler by modifying the backend. My end goal is that the script engine can support every part of C.

In terms of the scripts, I've already implemented a header file format for each script and have each script sandboxed by allowing them to have their own memory and stack allocated when loading. The script's data layout is...

```
typedef struct __script {
    uchar       *pMemory, *pStack, *pInstrStream;
    uint64_t            ip, sp, bp;     // 24 bytes

    uint        uiMemSize;      // how much memory does script need?
    uint        uiStkSize;      // how large of a stack does script need?
    uint        ipstart;        // where does 'main' begin?
    uint        uiInstrCount;   // how many instructions does the code have?
    uint16_t    magic;          // verify bytecode
} Script_t;
```

In terms of all this, I only have two real questions.

Q1: **Considering that each script is sandboxed, how can I have it so individual scripts can share data between one another?**

I thought up two ways to solve this issue:
1 way is I could hack up a bytecode linker and link multiple compiled bytecode scripts into one big one and use them as static libraries

another method I thought up was that scripts compiled without `main()` can act as a DLL (dynamically loaded), then a script can load in a dllscript and then use a specific data whether function or variable similar to `dlopen` and `dlsym` used in linux.

Q2: **What is the best way to bridge a public API between the VM and host application? (so that scripts can call native C code from host application side)**

Since this VM is to run bytecode made from a C compiler, I'm pretty sure that each script will have to include a header file that contains the host-exported function prototypes for scripts to use though I'm not sure how that would work out.

Then there's the issue with exporting host-side variables like structs, unions, globals, etc. I haven't thought about this part because I'm still thinking about solving the issue of question #1.

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Q1: are you referring to share data between different .c scrips intended to work together?

Comment: yessir, having different .c scripts compiled to bytecode working together at least in some, hopefully seamless form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1: Considering that each script is sandboxed, how can I have it so individual scripts can share data between one another?

A software made of several `.c` file is designed to work together, it make no sense to try executing a sub-set of them and they are designed to work in collaboration.

A sandbox has the reverse purpose: it intend to divide and protect individuals, by avoiding them having any impact on each others, avoiding communication, and avoiding collaboration.

Trying to make each `.c` file sandboxed, is IMO a wrong concept from the beginning and thus, any solution would be a patch, a security issue or both.

The solution is probably to consider this interaction closely from the sandbox perspective: A sandbox would encapsulate a software and not anymore a single `.c` file. We could imagine this sandbox to encapsulate several files, some memory management, some interface to devices, etc.. It would also require a way to define which files belong to the same software, maybe a meta-data file?

---

> Q2: What is the best way to bridge a public API between the VM and host application? (so that scripts can call native C code from host application side)

Supposing you got your syntactical tree out of the object code, it seem feasible to detect external libraries: usually a table indicate expected external functions signatures. You may then call the specific `C` function in case of a known signature (e.i. standard library calls).

Comment: about the first question. several `.c` files working together are usually linked together though. Are you saying I should go to the trouble of making a linker for each bytecode file generated from each individual `.c` file?

Comment: here's the github to the virtual machine https://github.com/assyrianic/Crown-Virtual-Machine

Comment: That is the assumption I did (by asking you in a comment) .  If that is not the case, what exactly are you interpreting? it is also what you seem to do from following sentence: " ...engine is to execute bytecode created from a normal C compiler..."

Comment: basically this is VM with enough features to run C code that's compiled to bytecode of course. Thus would I require building a bytecode linker or something else?

Comment: So what is the Q1 about? and why `C`?: If you are doing a VM and not a scripting engine. For executing any executable format, what sharing of data do you need?

Comment: well I want to use standard C as a scripting language. I know that's not its purpose but that's what I want to do. the VM is part of the scripting engine. The thing about Q1 is that the scripts will have their own memory and stack space, I have no linker so I can only rely on headers. Scripts might need to share data with other scripts which is why I'm asking what is the best route to take so the scripts can share data without having a security issue.

Comment: Ok, let start again: C source-code => [compiler] => object code => [linker] => executable.
What is your byte-code?

Comment: bytecode is the executable the VM can run. The way it'll work is... C source-code => [modified compiler] => compiled bytecode script. The issue still remains how each script will be able to communicate with one another.

Comment: Your "modified compiler" has no linker, so I assume you will have N bytecode scripts collaborating within a single program.Alright, here come the only-header! But that is a technical limitation, basically you are telling that any program producing more than 1 byte-code script cannot be run.

Comment: yes, the issue is having each script able to share data with one another. Each script has their own memory and stack allocated to them but then comes up with the issue of if a script needs to export data like functions or structs.

Comment: Next question: What "share data" means? networking, files, pipes, share memory? exporting data and functions only matter if you have several script per program.

Comment: share data from scripts between scripts, I just said that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62520/discussion-between-nergal-and-adrian-maire).